# How can I capture one frame using a Point Cloud Library?

Tags: c++, kinect, point-cloud-library

```
        // Sample_PCL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #define NOMINMAX
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <Kinect.h>                                 // Kinectを使用するためのヘッダファイル
    #include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>         // PCLを使用して表示するためのヘッダファイル
    #include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>                          // 点群データを保存するためのヘッダファイル(.pcd, .ply)
    //#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
    #include <pcl/point_types.h>
    #include <iostream>

    template<class Interface>
    inline void SafeRelease(Interface *& pInterfaceToRelease)
    {
        if (pInterfaceToRelease != NULL) {
            pInterfaceToRelease->Release();
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        // Create Sensor Instance
        IKinectSensor* pSensor;
        HRESULT hResult = S_OK;
        hResult = GetDefaultKinectSensor(&pSensor);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : GetDefaultKinectSensor" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("GetDfaultKinectSensor is OK\n");

        // Open Sensor
        hResult = pSensor->Open();
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::Open()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::Open is OK\n");

        // Retrieved Coordinate Mapper
        ICoordinateMapper* pCoordinateMapper;
        hResult = pSensor->get_CoordinateMapper(&pCoordinateMapper);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::get_CoordinateMapper()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::get_CoordinateMapper is OK\n");


        // Retrieved Color Frame Source
        IColorFrameSource* pColorSource;
        hResult = pSensor->get_ColorFrameSource(&pColorSource);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::get_ColorFrameSource()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::get_ColorFrameSource is OK\n");

        // Open Color Frame Reader
        IColorFrameReader* pColorReader;
        hResult = pColorSource->OpenReader(&pColorReader);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IColorFrameSource::OpenReader()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IColorFrameSource::OpenReader is OK\n");

        // Retrieved Depth Frame Source
        IDepthFrameSource* pDepthSource;
        hResult = pSensor->get_DepthFrameSource(&pDepthSource);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::get_DepthFrameSource()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::get_DepthFrameSource is OK\n");

        // Open Depth Frame Reader
        IDepthFrameReader* pDepthReader;
        hResult = pDepthSource->OpenReader(&pDepthReader);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IDepthFrameSource::OpenReader()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IDepthFrameSource::OpenReader is OK\n");

        // Retrieved Color Frame Size
        IFrameDescription* pColorDescription;
        hResult = pColorSource->get_FrameDescription(&pColorDescription);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IColorFrameSource::get_FrameDescription()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IColorFrameSource::get_FrameDescription is OK\n");

        int colorWidth = 0;
        int colorHeight = 0;
        pColorDescription->get_Width(&colorWidth); // 1920
        pColorDescription->get_Height(&colorHeight); // 1080

                                                     // To Reserve Color Frame Buffer
        std::vector<RGBQUAD> colorBuffer(colorWidth * colorHeight);

        // Retrieved Depth Frame Size
        IFrameDescription* pDepthDescription;
        hResult = pDepthSource->get_FrameDescription(&pDepthDescription);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IDepthFrameSource::get_FrameDescription()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IDepthFrameSource::get_FrameDescription is OK\n");

        int depthWidth = 0;
        int depthHeight = 0;
        pDepthDescription->get_Width(&depthWidth); // 512
        pDepthDescription->get_Height(&depthHeight); // 424

                                                     // To Reserve Depth Frame Buffer
        std::vector<UINT16> depthBuffer(depthWidth * depthHeight);

        printf("Display Point Cloud\n");

        // Create Cloud Viewer
        pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Point Cloud Viewer");       //  点群のウィンドウ表示

        while (!viewer.wasStopped()) {
            // Acquire Latest Color Frame
            IColorFrame* pColorFrame = nullptr;
            hResult = pColorReader->AcquireLatestFrame(&pColorFrame);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hResult)) {
                // Retrieved Color Data
                hResult = pColorFrame->CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(colorBuffer.size() * sizeof(RGBQUAD), reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&colorBuffer[0]), ColorImageFormat::ColorImageFormat_Bgra);
                if (FAILED(hResult)) {
                    std::cerr << "Error : IColorFrame::CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray()" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            SafeRelease(pColorFrame);

            // Acquire Latest Depth Frame
            IDepthFrame* pDepthFrame = nullptr;
            hResult = pDepthReader->AcquireLatestFrame(&pDepthFrame);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hResult)) {
                // Retrieved Depth Data
                hResult = pDepthFrame->CopyFrameDataToArray(depthBuffer.size(), &depthBuffer[0]);
                if (FAILED(hResult)) {
                    std::cerr << "Error : IDepthFrame::CopyFrameDataToArray()" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            SafeRelease(pDepthFrame);

            // Point Cloud Libraryの設定
            // Create Point Cloud
            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pointcloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>());     // PCLの構造体
            pointcloud->width = static_cast<uint32_t>(depthWidth);      // 点群の数
            pointcloud->height = static_cast<uint32_t>(depthHeight);
            pointcloud->is_dense = false;

            for (int y = 0; y < depthHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < depthWidth; x++) {
                    pcl::PointXYZRGB point;     // PCLで使用する点群情報

                    DepthSpacePoint depthSpacePoint = { static_cast<float>(x), static_cast<float>(y) };
                    UINT16 depth = depthBuffer[y * depthWidth + x];

                    // Coordinate Mapping Depth to Color Space, and Setting PointCloud RGB
                    ColorSpacePoint colorSpacePoint = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
                    pCoordinateMapper->MapDepthPointToColorSpace(depthSpacePoint, depth, &colorSpacePoint);     //  色の座標系
                    int colorX = static_cast<int>(std::floor(colorSpacePoint.X + 0.5f));
                    int colorY = static_cast<int>(std::floor(colorSpacePoint.Y + 0.5f));
                    if ((0 <= colorX) && (colorX < colorWidth) && (0 <= colorY) && (colorY < colorHeight)) {
                        RGBQUAD color = colorBuffer[colorY * colorWidth + colorX];
                        // 色の情報を格納する
                        point.b = color.rgbBlue;
                        point.g = color.rgbGreen;
                        point.r = color.rgbRed;
                    }

                    // Coordinate Mapping Depth to Camera Space, and Setting PointCloud XYZ
                    CameraSpacePoint cameraSpacePoint = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };           // カメラ空間
                    pCoordinateMapper->MapDepthPointToCameraSpace(depthSpacePoint, depth, &cameraSpacePoint);
                    if ((0 <= colorX) && (colorX < colorWidth) && (0 <= colorY) && (colorY < colorHeight)) {
                        // 直交座標系の情報を格納する
                        point.x = cameraSpacePoint.X;
                        point.y = cameraSpacePoint.Y;
                        point.z = cameraSpacePoint.Z;
                    }

                    pointcloud->push_back(point);
                }
            }

            // Show Point Cloud on Cloud Viewer
            viewer.showCloud(pointcloud);

            // Input Key ( Exit ESC key )
            if (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) < 0) {
                pcl::io::savePCDFile("PointCloud.pcd", *pointcloud);
                //pcl::io::savePLYFile("test_pcd2.ply", *pointcloud);           // 最後に取得した点群を保存
                printf("Save Point Cloud Data\n");

                //break;
            }
        }

        // End Processing
        SafeRelease(pColorSource);
        SafeRelease(pDepthSource);
        SafeRelease(pColorReader);
        SafeRelease(pDepthReader);
        SafeRelease(pColorDescription);
        SafeRelease(pDepthDescription);
        SafeRelease(pCoordinateMapper);
        if (pSensor) {
            pSensor->Close();
        }
        SafeRelease(pSensor);

        printf("Disconnect Kinect Sensor\n");



        return 0;
    }
```

The previous code is a code taken from a tutorial from the Point Cloud Library Website uses the Kinect to display a Point Cloud of what the Kinect sees in real time. Therefore The Point Cloud is constantly changing. That is why I would like to get just a frame, in other words, I would like the point cloud to freeze instead of constantly capturing new frames.

and here is my modification.

```
        // Sample_PCL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #define NOMINMAX
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <Kinect.h>                                 // Kinectを使用するためのヘッダファイル
    #include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>         // PCLを使用して表示するためのヘッダファイル
    #include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>                          // 点群データを保存するためのヘッダファイル(.pcd, .ply)
    //#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
    #include <pcl/point_types.h>
    #include <iostream>

    template<class Interface>
    inline void SafeRelease(Interface *& pInterfaceToRelease)
    {
        if (pInterfaceToRelease != NULL) {
            pInterfaceToRelease->Release();
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        // Create Sensor Instance
        IKinectSensor* pSensor;
        HRESULT hResult = S_OK;
        hResult = GetDefaultKinectSensor(&pSensor);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : GetDefaultKinectSensor" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("GetDfaultKinectSensor is OK\n");

        // Open Sensor
        hResult = pSensor->Open();
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::Open()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::Open is OK\n");

        // Retrieved Coordinate Mapper
        ICoordinateMapper* pCoordinateMapper;
        hResult = pSensor->get_CoordinateMapper(&pCoordinateMapper);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::get_CoordinateMapper()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::get_CoordinateMapper is OK\n");


        // Retrieved Color Frame Source
        IColorFrameSource* pColorSource;
        hResult = pSensor->get_ColorFrameSource(&pColorSource);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::get_ColorFrameSource()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::get_ColorFrameSource is OK\n");

        // Open Color Frame Reader
        IColorFrameReader* pColorReader;
        hResult = pColorSource->OpenReader(&pColorReader);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IColorFrameSource::OpenReader()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IColorFrameSource::OpenReader is OK\n");

        // Retrieved Depth Frame Source
        IDepthFrameSource* pDepthSource;
        hResult = pSensor->get_DepthFrameSource(&pDepthSource);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IKinectSensor::get_DepthFrameSource()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IKinectSensor::get_DepthFrameSource is OK\n");

        // Open Depth Frame Reader
        IDepthFrameReader* pDepthReader;
        hResult = pDepthSource->OpenReader(&pDepthReader);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IDepthFrameSource::OpenReader()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IDepthFrameSource::OpenReader is OK\n");

        // Retrieved Color Frame Size
        IFrameDescription* pColorDescription;
        hResult = pColorSource->get_FrameDescription(&pColorDescription);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IColorFrameSource::get_FrameDescription()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IColorFrameSource::get_FrameDescription is OK\n");

        int colorWidth = 0;
        int colorHeight = 0;
        pColorDescription->get_Width(&colorWidth); // 1920
        pColorDescription->get_Height(&colorHeight); // 1080

                                                     // To Reserve Color Frame Buffer
        std::vector<RGBQUAD> colorBuffer(colorWidth * colorHeight);

        // Retrieved Depth Frame Size
        IFrameDescription* pDepthDescription;
        hResult = pDepthSource->get_FrameDescription(&pDepthDescription);
        if (FAILED(hResult)) {
            std::cerr << "Error : IDepthFrameSource::get_FrameDescription()" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        printf("IDepthFrameSource::get_FrameDescription is OK\n");

        int depthWidth = 0;
        int depthHeight = 0;
        pDepthDescription->get_Width(&depthWidth); // 512
        pDepthDescription->get_Height(&depthHeight); // 424

                                                     // To Reserve Depth Frame Buffer
        std::vector<UINT16> depthBuffer(depthWidth * depthHeight);

        printf("Display Point Cloud\n");

        // Create Cloud Viewer
        pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Point Cloud Viewer");       //  点群のウィンドウ表示

        //while (!viewer.wasStopped()) {
            // Acquire Latest Color Frame
            IColorFrame* pColorFrame = nullptr;
            hResult = pColorReader->AcquireLatestFrame(&pColorFrame);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hResult)) {
                // Retrieved Color Data
                hResult = pColorFrame->CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(colorBuffer.size() * sizeof(RGBQUAD), reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&colorBuffer[0]), ColorImageFormat::ColorImageFormat_Bgra);
                if (FAILED(hResult)) {
                    std::cerr << "Error : IColorFrame::CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray()" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            SafeRelease(pColorFrame);

            // Acquire Latest Depth Frame
            IDepthFrame* pDepthFrame = nullptr;
            hResult = pDepthReader->AcquireLatestFrame(&pDepthFrame);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hResult)) {
                // Retrieved Depth Data
                hResult = pDepthFrame->CopyFrameDataToArray(depthBuffer.size(), &depthBuffer[0]);
                if (FAILED(hResult)) {
                    std::cerr << "Error : IDepthFrame::CopyFrameDataToArray()" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            SafeRelease(pDepthFrame);



            // Point Cloud Libraryの設定
            // Create Point Cloud
            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pointcloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>());     // PCLの構造体
            pointcloud->width = static_cast<uint32_t>(depthWidth);      // 点群の数
            pointcloud->height = static_cast<uint32_t>(depthHeight);
            pointcloud->is_dense = false;

            for (int y = 0; y < depthHeight; y++) {

                for (int x = 0; x < depthWidth; x++) {
                    //printf("scann\n");
                    pcl::PointXYZRGB point;     // PCLで使用する点群情報

                    DepthSpacePoint depthSpacePoint = { static_cast<float>(x), static_cast<float>(y) };
                    UINT16 depth = depthBuffer[y * depthWidth + x];

                    // Coordinate Mapping Depth to Color Space, and Setting PointCloud RGB
                    ColorSpacePoint colorSpacePoint = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
                    pCoordinateMapper->MapDepthPointToColorSpace(depthSpacePoint, depth, &colorSpacePoint);     //  色の座標系
                    int colorX = static_cast<int>(std::floor(colorSpacePoint.X + 0.5f));
                    int colorY = static_cast<int>(std::floor(colorSpacePoint.Y + 0.5f));
                    if ((0 <= colorX) && (colorX < colorWidth) && (0 <= colorY) && (colorY < colorHeight)) {
                        RGBQUAD color = colorBuffer[colorY * colorWidth + colorX];
                        // 色の情報を格納する
                        point.b = color.rgbBlue;
                        point.g = color.rgbGreen;
                        point.r = color.rgbRed;
                    }

                    // Coordinate Mapping Depth to Camera Space, and Setting PointCloud XYZ
                    CameraSpacePoint cameraSpacePoint = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };           // カメラ空間
                    pCoordinateMapper->MapDepthPointToCameraSpace(depthSpacePoint, depth, &cameraSpacePoint);
                    if ((0 <= colorX) && (colorX < colorWidth) && (0 <= colorY) && (colorY < colorHeight)) {
                        // 直交座標系の情報を格納する
                        point.x = cameraSpacePoint.X;
                        point.y = cameraSpacePoint.Y;
                        point.z = cameraSpacePoint.Z;
                    }

                    pointcloud->push_back(point);
                }
            //}

            viewer.showCloud(pointcloud);
            while (!viewer.wasStopped())
            {
            }
            /*pcl::io::savePCDFile("PointCloud.pcd", *pointcloud);
            printf("Saved Point Cloud Data\n");

            // Show Point Cloud on Cloud Viewer
            printf("Open viewer\n");
            viewer.showCloud(pointcloud);
            while (!viewer.wasStopped()) {

            }*/

            // Input Key ( Exit ESC key )
            if (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) < 0) {
                pcl::io::savePCDFile("PointCloud.pcd", *pointcloud);
                //pcl::io::savePLYFile("test_pcd2.ply", *pointcloud);           // 最後に取得した点群を保存
                printf("Save Point Cloud Data\n");

                //break;
            }
        }

        // End Processing
        SafeRelease(pColorSource);
        SafeRelease(pDepthSource);
        SafeRelease(pColorReader);
        SafeRelease(pDepthReader);
        SafeRelease(pColorDescription);
        SafeRelease(pDepthDescription);
        SafeRelease(pCoordinateMapper);
        if (pSensor) {
            pSensor->Close();
        }
        SafeRelease(pSensor);

        printf("Disconnect Kinect Sensor\n");



        return 0;
    }
```

The modification mainly consists of removing the loop that updates the point cloud constantly which is: You can see it commented in the second code.

```
while (!viewer.wasStopped())
```

The problem is that the the Point cloud viewer does not display any data received by the Kinect, and I would like to know the reason why it could not be displayed.

Comment: The two listings are identical.

Comment: Thank you @Dexter for pointing that out, I have just updated the code, Would you please look at it one more time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only seems to show the very first frame it receives from the Kinect, which might be empty or invalid. Did you check if the points in the cloud you're taking are sane?

However, you might want to approach the problem differently:

1. Leave the visualization loop as it is.
2. Register a key handler using `registerKeyboardCallback` ([doc](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_cloud_viewer.html)).
3. When a specific key is pressed, set a boolean to true.
4. In the visualization loop, if that boolean variable is true, skip the frame grabbing from the Kinect. It should retain the previously set cloud.